# URL Rewrite from domain.com/blog to domain.com

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have wordpress install on `example.com/blog` and now moved my webhosting & there I hosted my blog at `example.com`

Now, all my posts from `example.com/blog` are `example.com` with same URL structure.

So, how I can do URL rewrite with `.htaccess` to divert all traffic from `example.com/blog` to `example.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place this rule on **top of other rewrite rules**:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, for the real solution.